# Docker - library initialization failed - unable to allocate file descriptor table - out of memory

Tags: docker, apache-kafka, docker-compose, apache-zookeeper

I have been try to run Zookeeper and Kafka on Docker container.
I got a lot of errors `[error occurred during error reporting , id 0xb]` and `[Too many errors, abort]` in my terminal. And then `library initialization failed - unable to allocate file descriptor table - out of memory`.

I use the following docker-compose.yml file

```yaml
version: "3.8"
services:
  zookeeper:
    image: confluentinc/cp-zookeeper:5.5.4
    environment:
      ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT: 2181
      ZOOKEEPER_TICK_TIME: 2000
  kafka:
    image: confluentinc/cp-kafka:5.5.4
    # If you want to expose these ports outside your dev PC,
    # remove the "127.0.0.1:" prefix
    ports:
      - 127.0.0.1:9092:9092
    environment:
      KAFKA_BROKER_ID: 1
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper:2181
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://kafka:29092,PLAINTEXT_HOST://localhost:9092
      KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT,PLAINTEXT_HOST:PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME: PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
```

Comment: What is your host OS? How much memory does it have?

Comment: @OneCricketeer I used manjaro linux and i had 16gb Ram

Comment: Have you tried running other containers? And did you search the error? Seems to be an issue with Arch's default Docker installation (also used by Manjaro) https://github.com/neo4j/docker-neo4j/issues/155#issuecomment-471997631

Comment: Yes, only kafka vs zookeeper containers fail. Thank you, I will try it

Comment: @OneCricketeer I followed this guide,I trying my best but it working perfect... thanks very much

Comment: Feel free to answer below with the solution that worked for you

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I fixed this problem by override commands arguments `ExecStart` in docker.service

```sh
sudo systemctl edit docker
```

and then enter

```
[Service]
ExecStart=
ExecStart=/usr/bin/dockerd --default-ulimit nofile=65536:65536 -H fd://
```

Save and run `sudo systemctl daemon-reload` and `sudo systemctl restart docker`.

Comment: does some one knows  why this would work with this kind of error  ?

Answer (score 16):

Try to add ulimits configuration to zookeeper like that

```
---
version: '3'
services:
  zookeeper:
    image: wurstmeister/zookeeper
    ulimits:
      nofile:
        soft: 65536
        hard: 65536
    ports:
      - "2181:2181"
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that your kafka broker needs to have a dependency from  your zookeper.
This works for me:

```
---
version: '2'
services:
  zookeeper:
    image: confluentinc/cp-zookeeper:6.2.0
    hostname: zookeeper
    container_name: zookeeper
    ports:
      - "2181:2181"
    environment:
      ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT: 2181
      ZOOKEEPER_TICK_TIME: 2000

  broker:
    image: confluentinc/cp-server:6.2.0
    hostname: broker
    container_name: broker
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
    ports:
      - "9092:9092"
      - "9101:9101"
    environment:
      KAFKA_BROKER_ID: 1
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: 'zookeeper:2181'
      KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT,PLAINTEXT_HOST:PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://broker:29092,PLAINTEXT_HOST://localhost:9092
      KAFKA_METRIC_REPORTERS: io.confluent.metrics.reporter.ConfluentMetricsReporter
      KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      KAFKA_GROUP_INITIAL_REBALANCE_DELAY_MS: 0
      KAFKA_CONFLUENT_LICENSE_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      KAFKA_CONFLUENT_BALANCER_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      KAFKA_TRANSACTION_STATE_LOG_MIN_ISR: 1
      KAFKA_TRANSACTION_STATE_LOG_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      KAFKA_JMX_PORT: 9101
      KAFKA_JMX_HOSTNAME: localhost
      CONFLUENT_METRICS_REPORTER_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS: broker:29092
      CONFLUENT_METRICS_REPORTER_TOPIC_REPLICAS: 1
      CONFLUENT_METRICS_ENABLE: 'true'
      CONFLUENT_SUPPORT_CUSTOMER_ID: 'anonymous'
```

Comment: This won't cause the error in the question

Answer (score 0):

```
version: "3.9"
networks:
  nrixmw:
    driver: bridge
services:
  zookeeper:
    image: confluentinc/cp-zookeeper:latest
    ulimits:
      nofile:
        soft: 65536
        hard: 65536
    hostname: zookeeper
    ports:
      - 2181:2181
    environment:
      ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT: '2181'
      ZOOKEEPER_TICK_TIME: '2000'
    networks:
      - nrixmw
  broker:
    image: confluentinc/cp-kafka:5.4.2
    ulimits:
      nofile:
        soft: 65536
        hard: 65536
    hostname: broker
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
    ports:
      - 29092:29092
      - 9092:9092
      - 9101:9101
    environment:
      KAFKA_BROKER_ID: 1
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: 'zookeeper:2181'
      # KAFKA_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME: 'broker'
      KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT,PLAINTEXT_HOST:PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://broker:29092,PLAINTEXT_HOST://localhost:9092
      KAFKA_LISTENERS: 'PLAINTEXT://:29092,PLAINTEXT_HOST://:9092'
      KAFKA_AUTO_CREATE_TOPICS_ENABLE: 'true'
      KAFKA_DELETE_TOPIC_ENABLE: 'true'
      KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      KAFKA_TRANSACTION_STATE_LOG_MIN_ISR: 1
      KAFKA_TRANSACTION_STATE_LOG_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      KAFKA_GROUP_INITIAL_REBALANCE_DELAY_MS: 0
    networks:
      - nrixmw
    mem_limit: 6g
    restart: always
  schema-registry:
    image: confluentinc/cp-schema-registry:5.5.1
    ulimits:
      nofile:
        soft: 65536
        hard: 65536
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
      - broker
    ports:
      - "8081:8081"
    environment:
      SCHEMA_REGISTRY_HOST_NAME: schema-registry
      SCHEMA_REGISTRY_KAFKASTORE_CONNECTION_URL: 'zookeeper:2181'
    networks:
      - nrixmw
```

This is how i do it, hope fully this will solve your err.
My system conf - Linux sourav-tuf 5.15.114-2-MANJARO #1 SMP PREEMPT Sun Jun 4 10:32:43 UTC 2023 x86_64 GNU/Linux (24g ram)

i have a mint machine, where i dont need all these ulimits, and its still working, this is arch os prob maybe. not sure.

Answer (score 0):

I did try most of the solutions presented above this, without success. Finally, I started Jenkins container by adding `--ulimit nofile=8096:8096` in the docker run command.

For example:
`docker run -d --ulimit nofile=8096:8096 -p 8089:8080 -v ~/jenkins_home/jenkins:/var/jenkins_home --name jenkins jenkins:2.60.1`

Now the container is running successfully.